How do I find the Hermite Polynomial of this function?
I'm attempting to find the fifth degree polynomial interpolating the function $$f(x) = 2x\arctan(x) - \ln(x^2+1)$$ and its first derivative at the points $−1, 0, 1$.
In the multiple attempts I try this I get:
$$H_5(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}-\ln(2) + \frac{-\pi}{2}(x+1) + \ln(2)(x+1)^2 + (-\ln(2))(x+1)^2(x) + \frac{\ln(2)}{2}(x+1)^2(x^2)+\frac{2\ln(2)-\pi}{8}(x+1)^2(x)^2(x-1)$$
For reference, this is the divided differences table I used
$x_0$ |$\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln(2)$
$x_0$ |$\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln(2)$ | $\frac{-\pi}{2}$
$x_1$ |$0$                  | $\ln(2)-{\pi/2}$ |$\ln(2)$
$x_1$ |$0$ | $0$ | $\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln(2)$| $-\ln(2)$
$x_2$ |$\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln(2)$| $\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln(2)$| $\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln(2)$| $0$ | $\frac{\ln(2)}{2}$
$x_2$ |$\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln(2)$| $\frac{\pi}{2}$ | $\ln(2)$| $\ 2\ln(2)- (\pi/2)$| $\ln(2)-(\pi/4)$| $\frac{2\ln(2)-\pi}{8}$
After putting it all in a graph, I get:

As far as I'm aware, the red line ($H_5(x)$), should approximate the blue better. I can't see where I went wrong, if I even got something wrong. Can someone give this a look and see where I messed up? Thank you in advance.

In your fourth line of the table, shouldn't the last entry, $(\pi/2 - \ln 2) - \ln 2$ be $\pi/2 - 2 \ln 2$?

Also, the inputs: $(x,y,y') = (-1, \frac{\pi}{2} - \ln 2, -\pi/2), (0,0,0), (1,\frac{\pi}{2} - \ln 2, \pi/2)$ force the result to be an even function.

"the fifth degree polynomial of the function" should be "the fifth degree polynomial approximating (according to which criteria ?) the function"

@JeanMarie It’s meant to interpolate at the given points.

@Moo How did you simplify it?

You kinda lost me? How would the expression change if I just cancelled out terms?

Especially since the function doesn’t approximate well either.
